# In Excel, how do i check if item is part of one of 3 lists and return list name

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 3 lists:

Low (2  3   4   5)
Mid (6  7   8   9)
High (T J   Q   K   A)

I want to check if cell AB6 is part of which list and return a "L" "M" "H" depending on results

```
=IF(COUNTIF($AC$1:$AF$1,AB6),"L")
```

This works to check if cell is part of list low. However I struggled to create a follow-up in case it's not to check list Mid and return "M" and if it's not to return "H" (by elimination since it must be part of one of the 3 lists)

Any thoughts how to do it?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick a cell and enter:

```
=LOOKUP(AB6,{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"A","K""J","Q","T"},{"L","L","L","L","M","M","M","M","H","H","H","H","H"})
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!!! Was looking too complicated that it was. Nice trick!

Comment: @L4ucky  You are welcome.  Remember in `LOOKUP()` the **order of the tests** is important!

Answer (score 0):

If the lists could be set like on the image below, then you could use the formula:

```
=INDEX(A1:A3,MATCH(1,MMULT(--(B1:E3=A5),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B1:E3)^0)),0))
```

Adap the ranges to match yours.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time! appreciated